# Uniform Grid inside a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm in the development of a program that requires its own custom file manager/explorer.
It's pretty typical: I have a user-control (named FileItem) and it includes an Image (thumbnail) and a Label (file name).

The problem I'm experiencing is with the layout; I need it in a grid layout (so I'm using Uniform Grid which nails it), exactly like Windows Explorer when you're on icon view:

[image: Windows Explorer]

I also need to be able to select file, or multiple files etc. which ListBox does perfectly.
The problem is that I can't use both.

So I tried to insert a Uniform Grid inside a ListBox. The layout was great, but I couldn't select the files (as if the ListBox wasn't there).

A quick Google search suggested to just use a ListView, but it doesn't do a good job since it has fixed columns and rows (and at the program I'm working on the size will change).

So how can I exactly achieve both of the functionality of ListBox and Uniform Grid?

**Edit (Important):**
If you also need this look and want an answer I actually recommend WrapPanel and not Uniform Grid. It will automatically allow you to dynamically change the number of the rows according to the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the ListBox's `ItemsPanel` to a UniformGrid you can do this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Grid Item 1" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Grid Item 2" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Grid Item 3" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Grid Item 4" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Grid Item 5" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Grid Item 6" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Grid Item 7" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Grid Item 8" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Grid Item 9" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Grid Item 10" />
</ListBox>
```

You shouldn't have selection issues with this and the items will be displayed as you wanted.